# Images in web hosting public_html folder not showing

Tags: html, image, hosting

So, I hope this question doesn't annoy experts coz lets face it, I am a novice.
I want to get an answer as its key to my progressing with my website.

Say my website is www.example.com. I got this public hosting, and in the public_html folder i put a simple index.php file which works fine; "hello world" is displayed.

Then I put image_1.jpg in the public_html folder, and typed a direct path in my browser:: 
www.example.com/image_1.jpg. 
Nothing gets displayed, just a black screen. But, the image is seen if I do the same on wampserver.

Afterwords, i put an image tag in the index.php file as follows:

img src="image_1.jpg"

Even then, I see the "hello world" on top, but in place of the image, i see just this standard thumbnail of a broken image. What is going on? It works on wampserver. Is there something I am missing like viewing rights? When I redownload the image, it seems corrupted (I used filezilla to upload it, and download it back again to see if its fine). 
Are there any "rules" about putting images directly in the public_html folder and accessing them directly using your domain name like :: www.yourdomain.com/image1.jpg? because it works on Wampserver, not on public hosting.. 
Thanksss... I will (and I promise I will) send a beer to whoever can help me sort this out!

Comment: Yes, i actually have those image tags, they were not letting the entire tag show with I typed this question so I removed the <   and > tags just for typing's sake

Answer (score 0):

> Nothing gets displayed, just a black screen.

That means your images are there. If images don't exist on the server then you will get a 404. Try reuploading and changing (or hard refreshing) browser.